# Deploy .net core 7 to IIS with SignalR

Tags: c#, iis, signalr, .net-7.0

I am using ASP.NET Core 7. I enabled IIS on my local PC.

I then published the files to the `inetpub` folder, and configured everything.

The http requests are working and I can see the website at `localhost:5151`, the problem the SignalR requests are not working, and I don't know what the problem is, and how to solve it...

In Visual Studio, everything works as expected.

I also installed the .NET 7 hosting bundle...

I tried older solutions that I saw here on stack overflow like updating the `web.config` file without luck

Comment: Hi Dolev, could you share the error message in the browser console window?

Comment: You also can [enable the client side logging first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to investigate the issue. By the way, Windows PCs have a websocket limit of 10 connections.

Comment: I had a problem in my dll paths... before publishing,, thats was the problem sorry but my problem I didnt know how to enable logging so I didnt saw any problem

Comment: Glad to know that you have no other questions in this thread.